# For...of loop only returning last HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set event listeners for a list of HTML elements. The main code that does this is below:

```js
let pageIds = ['functions', 'lists', 'forLoops', 'lambda', 'maps'];
let pageLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('link');

    for (var l of pageLinks) {
        console.log(l.id)
        l.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log(l.id + ' was clicked');
            for (var x in pageIds) {
                document.getElementById(pageIds[x] + '-div').classList.remove('show');
            }
            document.getElementById(`${l.id}-div`).classList.add('show');
        })
    }
```

When using the `for` keyword, this loop should iterate through each element individually, and thus set an event listener for each element individually.

However, when I run this code, the `eventlistener` function does not work as it should.

When the page loads, the console properly outputs the following:

```
functions
lists
forLoops
lambda
maps
```

The issue happens when I then go and try to click on one of the links. The event listener only ever outputs the `maps` id, and nothing else. I don't understand why this would be happening since the first `console.log()` proved that things were reading properly, but then it broke by the time it got into the eventlistener code. Each time the loop runs, `l` is a different HTML element, and thus should not overwrite the one before it.

Is there something in my code that I am missing?

Comment: Change `var l` to `let l`.